# Golang handlers handling different types

Tags: go, dry

These are AppHandlers from a pattern I found online while researching gorilla/mux. They part of a struct that satisfies http.Handler. If you notice, the following two blocks are exactly the same. Effectively, they could be passed the 'variant' ("flow" or "process") as a string.

```
func CreateFlow(a *AppContext, w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) (int, error) {

    highest, code, err := a.Create("flow", r)
    if code != 200 || err != nil {
        return code, err
    }

    b := new(bytes.Buffer)
    json.NewEncoder(b).Encode(struct {
        Highest int `json:"id"`
    }{highest})
    w.Header().Set("Content-Type", "application/json")
    w.Write(b.Bytes())
    return 200, nil
}

func CreateProcess(a *AppContext, w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) (int, error) {

    highest, code, err := a.Create("process", r)
    if code != 200 || err != nil {
        return code, err
    }

    b := new(bytes.Buffer)
    json.NewEncoder(b).Encode(struct {
        Highest int `json:"id"`
    }{highest})
    w.Header().Set("Content-Type", "application/json")
    w.Write(b.Bytes())
    return 200, nil
}
```

However, the following two blocks not only need the string, but they need a variable of the associated type ("Flow" and "Process") to successfully Unmarshal the hit I get from ElasticSearch. Other than that, they are Identical code.

```
func GetFlow(a *AppContext, w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) (int, error) {

    hit, code, err := a.GetByID("flow", mux.Vars(r)["id"], r)
    if code != 200 {
        return code, err
    }

    var flow Flow

    err = json.Unmarshal(*hit.Source, &flow)
    if err != nil {
        return 500, err
    }

    flow.ESID = hit.Id

    b := new(bytes.Buffer)
    json.NewEncoder(b).Encode(flow)
    w.Header().Set("Content-Type", "application/json")
    w.Write(b.Bytes())
    return 200, nil
}

func GetProcess(a *AppContext, w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) (int, error) {

    hit, code, err := a.GetByID("process", mux.Vars(r)["id"], r)
    if code != 200 {
        return code, err
    }

    var process Process

    err = json.Unmarshal(*hit.Source, &process)
    if err != nil {
        return 500, err
    }

    process.ESID = hit.Id

    b := new(bytes.Buffer)
    json.NewEncoder(b).Encode(process)
    w.Header().Set("Content-Type", "application/json")
    w.Write(b.Bytes())
    return 200, nil
}
```

I am not sure how to generalize this behavior in golang when there is a declared type involved. These handlers are all in the same package too, as I think that they are all accomplishing a similar task. I am very clearly repeating myself in code but I need advice on how I can improve. I've gone past "a little copying is better than a little dependency." but I am afraid because "reflection is never clear".

Here is an example of the declaration in main using one of these functions.

```
api.Handle("/flow/{id:[0-9]+}", handlers.AppHandler{context, handlers.GetFlow}).Methods("GET")
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can do it by passing in an exemplar of the necessary type, the same way that `Unmarshal` does it:

```
func GetFlow(a *AppContext, w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) (int, error) {
    return GetThing(a,w,r,"flow",new(Flow))
}

func GetProcess(a *AppContext, w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) (int, error) {
    return GetThing(a,w,r,"process",new(Process))
}

func GetThing(a *AppContext, w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request, t string, ob Elastible{}) (int, error) {
    hit, code, err := a.GetByID(t, mux.Vars(r)["id"], r)
    if code != 200 {
        return code, err
    }

    err = json.Unmarshal(*hit.Source, ob)
    if err != nil {
        return 500, err
    }

    ob.SetESID(hit.Id)

    b := new(bytes.Buffer)
    json.NewEncoder(b).Encode(ob)
    w.Header().Set("Content-Type", "application/json")
    w.Write(b.Bytes())
    return 200, nil
}

type Elastible interface {
    SetESID(id ESIDType)    // whatever type ESID is, not clear from example
}

func (f *Flow) SetESID(id ESIDType) {
    f.ESID = id
}
```

This code is untested (because I don't have your struct defs or other dependent code) but I hope it gets the idea across.

Comment: That's awesome. Thank you for the response. I'll update after implementation.

Answer (score 2):

Alright, I propose a solution that will give you the maximum code reuse and minimum code copying. This, in my opinion, is by far the most generic solution. We will also take into account the answer given by https://stackoverflow.com/users/7426/adrian to complete the solution. You only have to define a single function which will be a higher order function `CreateHandler` which will return a function of the following signature: 

`func(*AppContext, http.ResponseWriter, http.Request) (int, error)`.

This signature is the actual signature of the handler that is to be used as a mux end point. The solution involves defining a `Handler` type which is a struct having three fields:

• `handlerType`: Think of it as an enum having either a value of `"CREATE"` or `"GET"`. This will decide which among the two blocks of code that you pasted in your question should we use.

• `handlerActionName`: This will tell the `"CREATE"` or `"GET"` which Elastible to use. Value should either be `"flow"` or `"process"`.

• `elastible`: This will the Interface type `Elastible` that will have the `SetESID` function. We will use this to send our `Flow` or `Process` types to our `Handler`. Thus both `Flow` and `Process` should satisfy our interface.
This will make the solution even more generic and will only calling `handler.elastible.SetESID()` and we will have inserted the ESID irrespective of that fact the underlying type in 'elastible' can either be 'Flow' or a 'Process'

I also define a `sendResponse(response interface{})` function that we will resuse to send the response. It acquires `w http.ResponseWriter` using closure. `response` can thus be anything, a

```
struct {
    Highest int `json:"id"`
}{highest}
```

or a `Flow` or a `Process`. This will make this function generic too.

The complete solution would now be.

```
// This is the type that will be used to build our handlers.
type Handler struct {
    handlerType       string    // Can be "CREATE" or "GET"
    handlerActionName string    // Can be "flow" or "process"
    elastible         Elastible // Can be *Flow or *Process
}

// Your ESID Type.
type ESIDType string

// Solution proposed by https://stackoverflow.com/users/7426/adrian.
type Elastible interface {
    SetESID(id ESIDType)
}

// Make the Flow and Process pointers implement the Elastible interface.
func (flow *Flow) SetESID(id ESIDType) {
    flow.ESID = id
}

func (process *Process) SetESID(id ESIDType) {
    process.ESID = id
}

// Create a Higher Order Function which will return the actual handler.
func CreateHandler(handler Handler) func(*AppContext, http.ResponseWriter, http.Request) (int, error) {

    return func(a *AppContext, w http.ResponseWriter, r http.Request) (int, error) {

        // Define a sendResponse function so that we may not need to copy paste it later.
        // It captures w using closure and takes an interface argument that we use to call .Encode() with.

        sendResponse := func(response interface{}) (int, error) {
            b := new(bytes.Buffer)
            json.NewEncoder(b).Encode(response)
            w.Header().Set("Content-Type", "application/json")
            w.Write(b.Bytes())
            return 200, nil
        }

        // Define these variables beforehand since we'll be using them
        // in both the if and else block. Not necessary really.
        var code int
        var err error

        // Check the handlerType. Is it create or get?
        if handler.handlerType == "CREATE" {
            var highest int

            // Creates the thing using handler.handlerActionName which may be "flow" or "process"
            highest, code, err = a.Create(handler.handlerActionName, r)
            if code != 200 || err != nil {
                return code, err
            }

            // Send the response using the above defined function and return.
            return sendResponse(struct {
                Highest int `json:"id"`
            }{highest})

        } else {

            // This is GET handlerType.
            var hit HitType

            // Get the hit using again the handler.handlerActionName which may be "flow" or "process"
            hit, code, err = a.GetByID(handler.handlerActionName, mux.Vars(r)["id"], r)
            if code != 200 || err != nil {
                return code, err
            }

            // Do the un-marshalling.
            err = json.Unmarshal(*hit.Source, ob)
            if err != nil {
                return 500, err
            }

            // We have set the handler.elastible to be an interface type
            // which will have the SetESID function that will set the ESID in the
            // underlying type that will be passed on runtime.
            // So the ESID will be set for both the Flow and the Process types.
            // This interface idea was given inside an earlier answer by
            // https://stackoverflow.com/users/7426/adrian

            handler.elastible.SetESID(hit.id)
            return sendResponse(handler.elastible)
        }
    }
}
```

And you would setup your mux end points using the following code.

```
    // This was your first function. "CreateFlow"
    api.Handle("/createFlow/{id:[0-9]+}", handlers.AppHandler{
        context, CreateHandler(Handler{
            elastible:         &Flow{},
            handlerActionName: "flow",
            handlerType:       "CREATE",
        }),
    }).Methods("GET")

    // This was your second function. "CreateProcess"
    api.Handle("/createProcess/{id:[0-9]+}", handlers.AppHandler{
        context, CreateHandler(Handler{
            elastible:         &Process{},
            handlerActionName: "process",
            handlerType:       "CREATE",
        }),
    }).Methods("GET")

    // This was your third function. "GetFlow"
    api.Handle("/getFlow/{id:[0-9]+}", handlers.AppHandler{
        context, CreateHandler(Handler{
            elastible:         &Flow{},
            handlerActionName: "flow",
            handlerType:       "GET",
        }),
    }).Methods("GET")

    // This was your fourth function. "GetProcess"
    api.Handle("/getProcess/{id:[0-9]+}", handlers.AppHandler{
        context, CreateHandler(Handler{
            elastible:         &Process{},
            handlerActionName: "process",
            handlerType:       "GET",
        }),
    }).Methods("GET")
```

Hope it helps!

Comment: Thank you very much for the detailed response. I'll take a crack at implementing what you suggested (superset of Adrian's) and get back to you. I'd omitted the other REST calls for simplicity, there are deletes and by necessity options. Also gets with a large set. I will take some time to try and generalize.

Comment: Adrian's solution seems much simpler and easier to understand / maintain. Being more generic here seems to come at the cost of complexity / readability and IMO isn't worth it unless you really need it. Of course, 99% of the time the YAGNI principle applies :-)

Comment: YAGNI principle would apply if I were getting paid for this project ;)